# gnuplot xrange min does not show

Tags: gnuplot

I have my dataset (d.asc) as follows:

```
0.1 0.5
0.12 0.56
...
90.4 0.34
...
100 0.78
```

I have my plot generation file as follows:

```
set xrange [0.1:100]
set grid
plot "d.asc" using 1:2 notitle with lines
```

I.e. I want to see first column on x-axis, and second column on y-axis. But, the x-axis values start from 0 and increment by 10 upto 100.

[1] Why it does not start from 0.1?

[2] Also is there a way to have only three (or four, etc.) specific value points on x-axis? For example I want to see on x-axis only 0.1, 90.4, and 100. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[1] Why it does not start from 0.1?**

Gnuplot likes to pick round numbers for its tic increments and positions.  In your case the increments are 10, so they would appear at 0, 10, ... 100.  Since you manually set the x range to start at 0.1 a tic does not appear until 10.

**[2] Also is there a way to have only three (or four, etc.) specific value points on x-axis?**

Yes, you can specify specific points with this syntax:

```
set xtics ("0.1" 0.1, "90.4" 90.4, "100" 100)
```

The value in quotes is the text that appears at the tic, and the number is the actual position at which it appears.  (`help set xtics` for more format info.)